# Registering many objects in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a model that should have the same structure and behavior in both browser and server. To be able to reuse code, I choose NodeJS. It was not so trivial task I thought, but thanks to [this article](http://sebastianpatten.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/node-sharing-javascript-code-between-client-and-server/) now I can write universal code.

I faced with a problem when tried to serialized my model. Each class of objects should have its own ID (like `a.b.C`), so when object will be serialized, this ID is added to JSON and then used to create empty object to deserialize it to.

It means that when we get JSON, we need to take ID, then find module by it, then create empty object and fill it. So, we need to have map of modules IDs and modules. Will name it "Register".

Register needs to be initialized. To do it, we need to load all dependencies before serializing starts. If we will do it in the regular RequireJS way, it will looks like:

```
define([
    "odm/model/core/serializing/Person",
    "odm/model/core/serializing/Man"
],
    function (require, Person, Man) {
        var register = {
            _name_cls:{},
            _cls_name:{}
        };
        register.register = function (names) {
            for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                var name = names[i];
                var cls = require(name);
                register._name_cls[name] = cls;
                register._cls_name[cls] = name;
            }
        };
        register.byName = function (name) {
            return register._name_cls[name];
        };
        register.byCls = function (name) {
            return register._cls_name[name];
        };

        register.register([
            "odm/model/core/serializing/Person",
            "odm/model/core/serializing/Man"
        ]);

        return register;
    });
```

As you can see, to register new object we need to add it manually in the 3 places in register - link to a module, module as argument in function parameters and module as argument of register(names) function.

Are there any simplier way of registering objects?

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate the register module from the other modules to be registered:

#### register.js:

```
define(function (require) {
    var register = {
        _name_cls:{},
        _cls_name:{}
    };
    register.register = function (names) {
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            var name = names[i];
            var cls = require(name);
            register._name_cls[name] = cls;
            register._cls_name[cls] = name;
        }
    };
    register.byName = function (name) {
        return register._name_cls[name];
    };
    register.byCls = function (name) {
        return register._cls_name[name];
    };

    return register;
});
```

#### register-all.js

Use `Array.prototype.slice` to get the module parameters.

```
define(["register", "odm/model/core/serializing/Person", "odm/model/core/serializing/Man"], function (register) {
    var modules = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    register.register(modules);
});
```